# Communication between Gunicorn and Nginx

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I have been trying to run my django production server using Gunicorn as my application server and Nginx as a reverse proxy.

Below is my nginx conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myproject.com;

    location /static/ {
        alias /var/www/myproject/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /var/www/myproject/media/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }            
}
```

Below is my gunicorn.conf file:

```
description "Gunicorn application server handling my project file"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
setuid user
setgid www-data
chdir /home/user/myproject/

exec gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/user/myproject/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application
```

Below is the code for myproject.sock file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn/socket
ListenStream=0.0.0.0:9000
ListenStream=[::]:8000

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

When I try to run with these settings. I get the following error:

```
connect() to unix:/home/user/myproject/myproject.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream
```

It would be great if anyone can help me understand what i am doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what that myproject.sock is supposed to be. A unix socket is not really a file, it's just something that processes use to communicate; it can't have any actual content.

Comment: Thanks DanielRoseman, that makes sense, my initial understanding was that it will contain some kind of information on how gunicorn and nginx will communicate in reference to the project. So how can i setup a Unix Socket or any guide where i can understand how to setup a socket. Thanks again

Comment: I guess you are trying out this tutorial for deploying. http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html#upstart . upstart and systemd are two different tools. Only use any one. And how are you trying to run the project?

Answer (score -2):

Suppose you are run Ubuntu 14.04:

Step1:
First you can install and run django with gunicorn in virtualenv.Here, it doesn't matter with nginx, but you can get the feedback from Django and gunicorn altogether.

Step2:
Then it's time to do with nginx for a robust way.

Make sure step 1 is on green light then jump to step 2, so you can isolate any trouble in different stage.